# Windows randomly reidentifies network connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

I run into problem when my laptop randomly drop wireless network connection and attempts to reconnect to it, in other words if you would look at network status it would change from Connected - Internet Access, to Connected - Identifying and few seconds after going back to Connected - Internet Access, however with massive packet losses. After that event occurs it's becomes unreal to even log on to router to do a reboot as browser would only receive headler on page and then wait for the rest forever. 
Other facts i noticed:

-Even when laptop is unable to communicate to router (ping indicated 50-75% packet losses, and web interface never gets loaded completely), no other device have problem with network.

-Affected laptop don't have any problems with any other wireless network

-If affected laptop connects to that network using my cellphone as hot-spot, everything is fine.

-Resetting router to factory settings helped only once for about a month.

-Reboot of router solves problem for 10-15 minutes.

Any ideas of what i should inspect would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to delete the configuration for that wireless network from your laptop and connect to it again? You can find your stored wireless network on the left hand side of your network center

Comment: I've done that. As well as re installation of drivers.